# Adding an existing project through Github using the command line (terminal)

Tags: github, terminal

I am having issues with adding an existing project through Github using terminal. I used the following commands:

In Terminal, add the URL for the remote repository where your local repository will be pushed.

```
# Sets the new remote
git remote add origin remote repository URL

# Verifies the new remote URL
git remote -v
```

Push the changes in your local repository to GitHub.

```
# Pushes the changes in your local repository up to the remote repository 
# you specified as the origin
git push origin master
```

**It came with the following results:**

```
remote: Permission to Bloc/bloc-jams-student-skeleton.git denied to ynoorstani.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Bloc/bloc-jams-student-skeleton.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Any helpful tips or insight would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

You could write to this repo (push) only if you were part of the Bloc organization members ([here is the list](https://github.com/orgs/Bloc/people)).

Since you are not in that list, you would need to [fork that repo](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/) in order to push to it.

Comment: I've tried forking the repo and it came up with the following results:

remote: Permission to Bloc/bloc-jams-student-skeleton.git denied to ynoorstani.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Bloc/bloc-jams-student-skeleton.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403